How to include commands defined in another file inside a class?
For documents 'import' and 'include' seem to work fine, inside the document environment.
However, if I am writing a class (template) for my own use, and I have defined commands in a dynamically generated file (ex. blah_commands.tex), how do I include blah_commands in my class/package?
Seems that the best approach currently still is to generate the additional macro file out of band, and include it as a package via RequirePackage.
Suits my use-case.

\input{blah_commands}

Does your dynamic generation method require you to close the file for writing, before you can read it via input?

@rallg I ended up resorting to RequirePackage and making the generated source as a sty. I was suspecting that no other solution presently exists.
And yes, unfortunately I needed this to overcome the limitations of datatool. I need to generate tables from explicit entries in a CSV without incurring in a multiple load/repeated processing of the file. Eventually I used a comb. of macros and macro expansion to define the entries as a subset, which I can use in the class and documents. The entries are static (think categories, etc).

I don't understand the difficulty here. why is using \RequirePackage 'resorting' to it? what is sub-optimal about this method? why can't you use \input{} if you don't want it to be a .sty? and what limitations of datatool (which isn't mentioned and you've given no example) are you trying to overcome? if you really want to know whether other solutions exist, you need to explain what problem you're trying to solve.

please don't edit answers into the question, post a self-answer if you wish. It isn't clear why you want to use \RequirePackage rather than \input either is fine, the former is most natural if the file is defining commands to be used possibly outside this class, the latter is more natural (and a bit more efficient)  if it really is just a constituent part of the main class.

You can actually use the command \InputIfFileExists{<file>}{<true>}{<false>}. This is sort of a safety mechanism if you LaTeX doesn't find your file. If you do \InputIfFileExists{blah_commands.tex}{}{} then it will input the file blah_commands.tex if it exists, and if not it will ignore this.
Here is a MWE using file contents:
\begin{filecontents}{myclass.cls}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2024/12/14 Custom Class Example]

% Include blah_commands.tex if it exists
\InputIfFileExists{blah_commands.tex}{}{}

% Define class options and setup
\DeclareOption*{}
\ProcessOptions\relax

% Basic class definitions
\LoadClass{article}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{blah_commands.tex}
% Commands defined in the external file
\newcommand{\examplecommand}{This is a dynamically included command!}
\end{filecontents}

% Main Document
\documentclass{myclass}

\begin{document}

\section*{Testing Dynamic Inclusion}
\examplecommand

\end{document}


